# Regression of discrete continuous averaged data

Tags: regression, interpolation

If I have data that is continuous and discrete that is the average of a timestep. For example average power usage over the past 1 hour that is continually sampled every hour. How could I turn such data into data with a 1 minute timestep?

Comment: You need to decide how you're going to interpolate. Nearest? Linear? Cubic splines? What are the design requirements for your interpolation?

Comment: Linear interpolation can get very high peaks and low valleys and is generally erratic when the data represents an average such as this data, but I am not sure how to represent the data with any higher order representation

Comment: Why don't you post a picture of your data, and what you want to get out of it?